# How to include dll's in a project I'm turning into a dll.

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2010, dll

I have a project that I want to turn into a dll. This project is already using some dll's. When I'm converting this project into a dll i want to bundle these other dll's in with this (new dll / project being turned into a dll). So when i'm using the newly created dll, I do not have to add the other dll's that the new one was using before it was turned into a dll.

Is this possible?

Comment: I think you will have to search for IL merging

Comment: Do you want to statically link the dll?

Comment: yeah I think that would be easiest. The dll's themselves as well as their locations wouldnt be changing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try to merge the referenced assemblies into your assembly using ilmerge.

Have a look at this [codeproject article](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/9364/Merging-NET-assemblies-using-ILMerge) for more information about ilmerge